# Babel documentation since the 7 upgrade is very confusing

Tags: babeljs

I'm posting this here because if I post it on the babel GitHub I get told it's not a bug and to start a post here. So here goes.

Since I started using Babel 7 a lot of issues in development are because of Babel issues. One day I installed a babel plugin and noticed a red warning and a link to a blog post about removing staging.

Yet nowhere is there a comprehensive guide on how to use babel without staging. Considering a lot of people will be jumping from babel 6 to babel 7 I feel it's kind of important. The decision to remove staging from what I read is to define the transforms and plugins explicitly.

I don't knock that decision, but how are people who relied on staging meant to make the switch?

I've been wandering about babel 7 for a few weeks now and end up falling into problems that cause painful hours of Googling because most of the results are for previous babel versions.

Today I got a warning about `decoratorBeforeExport` not being set. So I headed to the docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators

Nowhere on that page does it say `decoratorBeforeExport` is required.

A lot of tutorials and guides are on older versions that will not be compatible with 7 and as a seasoned developer - however stupid I may be - I struggled. And if I struggled you can bet your bottom dollar many others will.

I hope I'm wrong and there already exists information on this. But I can't find it.

Comment: Instead of stage *presets* install individual plugins

Comment: @Li357 I know this and I said that above, but that still doesn't solve any of the above problems.

Comment: Any luck tracking down guides for 7?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate an app to Babel 7 and would get the error saying I either need decoratorBeforeExport or legacy, but if I put either of those options in there as documented, I still get the same error. Babel indeed